# Where statement based on two images in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to replace the value in a raster using a `.where` statement in GEE based on conditions in two images. However, GEE appears to only be evaluating the second image, not conditions in both images together. For example, in the below code I want to reclass anything with DSWE=4 and slope>5% to class 7. But the code below seems to only account for the slope image but not the NDVI image.

```
var dswe_reclass=img_indices_all.map(function(img){
      var reclass=img.select("DSWE")
      reclass = reclass.where(img.select('DSWE').eq(4) && slope.gte(5.71),7);
return img.addBands(reclass)
});
```

How do use a conditional `.where` statement that looks at two images simultaneously to change the conditions in an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript `&&` operator cannot be used meaningfully on Earth Engine images — it will always just return the first image. Use `.and()` instead:

```js
reclass = reclass.where(img.select('DSWE').eq(4).and(slope.gte(5.71)), 7);
```